# Simple SQL query syntax error in controller asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I tried to convert to int like other selects, but this case is a multiselect and the foreach doesn't work with type int. I tried this and it worked: (but)....

```
//var id_status = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_status"]);    
var id_status = Request.Form["id_status"];
var id_cliente = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id_cliente"]);

var sql = "SELECT * FROM ativacao INNER JOIN cliente ON ativacao.id_cliente = cliente.id WHERE ativacao.id_cliente =" + id_cliente;

if (id_status != null)
{
    foreach (var itemselecionado in id_status)
    {
        sql = sql + " OR ativacao.status = '" + itemselecionado + "'";
    }
}
```

However, this foreach is working even with the commas, that is SQL query isn't working.

How can I get correct SQL query?

Final value of the SQL variable:

```
"SELECT * FROM ativacao 
INNER JOIN cliente 
ON ativacao.id_cliente = cliente.id 
WHERE ativacao.id_cliente =106 
AND cliente.id_prospector = 2 
AND cliente.id_executivo = 1 
AND cliente.ano_cliente = '2015' 
-->    OR ativacao.status = '4' 
    OR ativacao.status = ',' 
    OR ativacao.status = '5' 
    OR ativacao.status = ',' 
    OR ativacao.status = '6'   <--
```

I'm sorry if I cant explain very well, I don't know English very well.

Every help will be appreciated so much.

Comment: what is the data type for id_cliente?

Comment: Can you show what is the final value of the _sql_ variable?

Comment: Of couse, I'll edit the post with what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can just do this in your foreach loop:

```
if(itemselecionado == ',') continue;
```

Comment: .trim doesn't exist on asp.net

Comment: @FlávioAugusto After seeing results of your query, you just have to ignore the commas with an if statement and continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use in clause here. It will be easy to create and produce good query too. Here is the code for that:

```
if (id_status != null)
{
   string inClause = " ativacao.status in (";
   foreach (var itemselecionado in id_status)
   {
     if(itemselecionado.Trim() == ",")
     {
         countinue;
     }
     inClause += "'" + itemselecionado + "',";
   }
   inClause = inClause.SubString(0, inClause.Length - 1) + ")";
   sql = sql + inClause;
}
```

**Edit**: Your query will look like this one.

```
"SELECT * FROM ativacao INNER JOIN cliente ON 
ativacao.id_cliente = Cliente.id WHERE ativacao.id_cliente = 106 AND
cliente.id_prospector = 2
AND cliente.id_executivo = 1 AND cliente.ano_cliente = '2015'
OR ativacao.status in ('4', '5', '6')"
```

Thanks

Comment: When I posted, my problem was the commas and I fix it... but now I have other, the sintaxe OR is wrong. something like you answer will help. but where do I put "and" and "or"?

Comment: AND (ativacao.status = 3 
OR ativacao.status = 4 
OR ativacao.status = 8 )